# circular div inner shadow on bottom

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I want to have inner shadow  only on bottom semicircle of my circular div but shadow seems moving on wrong edges.

[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/704uc796/11/)

important part from code which does not work:

```
box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 3px -1px #000;
```

What I want is slightly different from those in fiddle :

[image]

Some may call this as an inset shadow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's what you mean:

```
.floating-circle{
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: blue;
width: 100px;
padding-top: 100px;
position: absolute;
box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 3px #000;
}
```

edit, so maybe like this, but without blur:

```
.floating-circle{
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #00008B;
    width: 100px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.floating-circle::after{
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    bottom:5px; 
    left:0;
}
```

main element should be "shadow" color, pseudo element should be your main color

3rd try :P with blur, of course You can manipulate blur amount, pesudo element width/height and position to achiver right amount of inner shadow:

```
.floating-circle{
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #00008B;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.floating-circle::after{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    bottom:-5px; 
    left:-10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -20px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

i'am afraid there always be some little artifacts, but there are some technics that can make them less visible, translateZ(0) or something like that - try it yourself :)

edit, with percent values:

```
.floating-circle{
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #00008B;
    width: 70%; /*can be %/px/vw or anything else */
    height: 70%; /*can be %/px/vw or anything else */
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden; /*disable this to better see what exactly is happeing with shadow*/
}

.floating-circle::after{
    border-radius: 55%;
    width: 110%;
    height: 110%;
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    bottom:-5%; 
    left:-5%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -20px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

you can now set .floatin-circle width/height to percent value or pixels value, and shadow should always work pretty good - you can "tweak" amount of shadow, by rgba opacity color or moving it up and down with "bottom" value or play with box-shadow props :)

Comment: it's at the bottom but it seems to extend to upper semicircle and that's bad for me! I need it to drop **ONLY** on bottom semicircle.

Comment: Thanx @Damian Martyniuk for your help and effort. Good news is that you made it stop at bottom but bad news is that it's creating a very small border for all around the circle in my Chrome browser. Also the project owner will want that shadow blur!

Comment: one more try :)

Comment: your answer is correct with my current question so i mark it as answer, but if you could give an answer in which width of the circle and the pseudo element were percent value, i would also up-vote your answer. with current update the shadow will disappear if i change the values to percent.